# Google Analytics _setCustomVar - strange data in my dashboard

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, analytics

I have set up the _setCustomVar for my website, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.blog4ever.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'B4E_Type_Pub', 'Silver_ou_Gold', 3]);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'B4E_Etat_Blog', 'normal', 3]);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

In my dashboard, when I go in: Visitors -> Custom variables, I see my 2 variables but the numbers are really strange (like 40 pages views although I have many thousands pages views).

I have it installed for 2 days now.

Did somebody face the same problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're lucky even 40 pageviews recorded these variables.

You need to call `_setCustomVar` before _trackPageview. Otherwise, the `_trackPageview` call sends the data to Google Analytics, and only after that are the custom variables set. If you set the `_setCustomVar` after the `_trackPageview`, the custom variable data doesn't attach, and if no other `__utm.gif` hits are set during that pageview, the data is basically gone forever.

(Those 40 pageviews that recorded probably were tracked via some other on-page GA calls that are sending data after the pageview loads).

Comment: This really helped me too, thanks! `_trackPageview` at the end and the custom variables start to appear the next day!

Comment: Worth noting: The only exception is visitor level custom variables; those will set in the cookie, and will thus record for subsequent pageviews after they've initially been set.

Comment: @yahelc I'm not convinced about this - I've been seeing this same behavior using visitor level custom variables (1 for the last parameter)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Yeah, my caveat is not be accurate anymore. Those visitor level custom variables, if recorded after the visit start pageview, will only record in GA on subsequent visits. (At one point, GA Custom Variables recorded 'hits' (pageviews with that variable) in addition to 'visits' (visits that started with that variable), but it seems like it only has the latter now.