# Google Analytics _setCustomVar

Tags: google-analytics

I have two different _setCustomVar events and I'm wondering if the second _gaq.push() is being triggered properly after the initial one.

Using GA Debugger in Chrome, I can see that the initial push is being processed.

```
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[29,node,true,3]":
```

And then I see that the tracking beacon is being sent and can confirm this with the utm.gif request params.

However, when I push the second custom variable, onComponentDidMount (react) I see the log,

```
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[32,text,true,2]":
```

but I don't see a subsequent "tracking beacon sent" log or utm.gif request made.

When exactly does GA dispatch the utm request?  Should all my custom variables be pushed onto the gaq array before the initial dispatch, or does a subsequent push to the gaq array automatically trigger a new dispatch?

This post says that you need to set all custom variables before you actually set the `_trackPageview` [Google Analytics _setCustomVar - strange data in my dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191408/google-analytics-setcustomvar-strange-data-in-my-dashboard)

Also, I don't see either custom variable in the reporting section of the GA admin tools.  All I see are the Custom Variable (Key 1) - Custom Variable (Key 5) links.  Shouldn't these custom variables show up as key 29 and 32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom variable must be followed by a hit (pageview, event etc) to be processed (see the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)), so I assume your second variable is set after your pageview.

At this time you should not use _setCustomVar at all - Google has switched completely to Universal Analytics and while they provide some degree of backwards compatibility with the previous tracking code you really should not rely on it as the Universal Analytics Upgrade Center has announced that [support for the ga.js tracking library will be discontinued](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/#phase-4). You should switch to custom dimensions instead, even if they don't quite provide the same functionality.